# Very high memory usage for CGBitmapContextCreate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

I'm using the following code to take a screenshot of a drawing at touchesEnded on my iOS app:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

    if(_pagessavedbg.count > selectedIndex)
        self.topimage = [_pagessavedbg objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];

    else
        self.topimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BlankImage.png"];

    UIImage *bottomimage = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"Image"];

    CGSize size = activeView.frame.size;

    NSUInteger width = size.width * 2;
    NSUInteger height = size.height * 2;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    memset(rawData,0,height * width * 4);

    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGRect bounds;
    bounds.origin = CGPointMake(0,0);
    bounds.size = size;

    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 2.0, 2.0);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), [self.topimage CGImage]);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), [bottomimage CGImage]);

    CGImageRef imageRef2 = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *latest2 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef2 scale:0.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];

    activeView.layer.contentsScale = 2.0;
    [activeView.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *latest = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:0.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef2);
    free(rawData);

    [_pages replaceObjectAtIndex:_sidebar.selectedIndex withObject:latest];

    [_sidebar reloadData];

    if(_pages.count > selectedIndex)
    {
    if([_pages objectAtIndex:selectedIndex])
    [_pages replaceObjectAtIndex:selectedIndex withObject:latest];

    if([_pagessavedbg objectAtIndex:selectedIndex])
    [_pagessavedbg replaceObjectAtIndex:selectedIndex withObject:latest2];

    else
    [_pagessavedbg insertObject:latest2 atIndex:selectedIndex];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.sidebar reloadData];
    [self.sidebar scrollRowAtIndexToVisible:_sidebar.selectedIndex];
    });    


});
```

However, every time this code is called (at touchesEnded), the memory usage goes up by about 10MB. Why is this happening? Is there a better, alternative way to doing this which would use *much* less memory?

Comment: You do realize that this is going to create copies of the raw image data. For a retina ipad thats 2048 * 1536 * 4 bytes per pixel thats almost exactly 12mb - nothing you can do about it other than downsizing the view before rendering.

Comment: So I can't reduce this enormous memory usage in any way?

Comment: your talking about the memory usage during the code execution not a memory leak correct?

Comment: You could eliminate the alpha channel of the image which would reduce the memory usage by 25% or 3 MB. Change your malloc to (width * height * 3) and change your bytesPerPixel and bytesPerRow accordingly. Then change the format at the end from kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast to kCGImageAlphaNone. Not 100% positive on those exact changes but that should get you on the right road.

Comment: The memory increase is cause by the malloc which is used to store the data for the bitmap context. Raw images use a lot of data not a ton you can do except what I mentioned above.

Comment: You could create a bitmap context using a vm-backed buffer--that could help.

Comment: I have some code that uses a VM buffer for writing large PDFs here: https://gist.github.com/3748250. You could perhaps adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Justin notes, 2048 * 1536 * 4 = 12MB. That fact is math and cannot be avoided. However, there are lots of ways to manage your memory utilization if allocating 12MB is a problem (that's not really that much memory on 1GB device for short-term usage, so you should ask what problem you're trying to solve, but anyway....)

- If you do this a lot, don't reallocate the memory. Reuse it. That way you only pay for it once.
- If you don't need a 2048*1536*4 image, create a smaller bitmap and scale your images to fit into it.
- Allocate smaller bitmaps and render parts of the images into them. Stitch them together later.

But do you have a target memory allocation in mind? While the retina display has been a major memory problem for many apps, a short-lived 12MB allocation usually isn't the problem. More often it's the time required, not the memory.

If you must have a 2048*1536*4 bitmap, though, it's going to take 12MB of memory.

Comment: I'd also add that you shouldn't hold on to the resulting UIImage from the above code any longer than you need to. It appears that this image is being sent to a background saving process in the above code, but you want to make sure it gets deallocated as soon as that saving is done.

Comment: After hearing what @BradLarson said, how can I deallocate it once the saving is done?

Comment: @d3v3l0p3r101 - Make sure that you remove the UIImage from any arrays or other collections that might hold on to it, release it properly (if under manual reference counting), and remove references to it from all properties. Basically, treat it like any other object whose usefulness has come to an end.

Comment: Good summary thanks. Any thoughts on create a bitmap context without the alpha channel? Is that not valid for rendering a layer into?

Comment: @JustinMeiners: [These are the formats that CGBitmapContext supports.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB) As you can see, there are no 24- or 48-bit formats, only 32- and 64-bit formats where one quarter of each pixel is either used for alpha or unused.